# Mysql convert FLOAT to DECIMAL

Tags: mysql, database, floating-point, decimal

I have mysql DB with important financial data, currently the data is stored as float type and I get incorrect data due to float rounding, I want to store it as DECIMAL.

What is the safe way to convert the data in the DB without change existing data? or any another idea to solve that issue?

**EDIT:** Does converting from FLOAT to VARCHAR and than from VARCHAR to DECIMAL is a safe way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just alter the column's data type `ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col decimal(P,S);`

Comment: Are you sure this us save on the existing data as is?

Comment: Why don't you test it and see?

Comment: Tested it and the data was updated to me, maybe you got something different if you wrote that answer.

Comment: Please find the largest amount you have.  And tell us how many decimal places are needed.  If you are really using `FLOAT` (as opposed to `DOUBLE`) some of the data may _already_ be lost.)

Comment: @RickJames Data is already lost so I must fix it but without touch the old data. What should I do?

Comment: @Esther-I - What is the largest number in that column?  (`SELECT MAX(price) ...`)  (If it can be negative, use ABS as well.)

Comment: @RickJames `13815500`

Answer (score 0):

There is no safe way.  Due to how floats work, 32 bit floats greater than 16777216 (or less than -16777216) need to be even, greater than 33554432 (or less than -33554432) need to be evenly divisibly by 4, greater than 67108864 (or less than -67108864) need to be evenly divisibly by 8, etc.

Comment: Please explain further.  (You are trying to say that beyond about 7 significant digits, data is _lost_.)

Comment: @Andrew If we convert from FLOAT to VARCHAR and then from VARCHAR to DECIMAL, is it safe?

Comment: The loss of accuracy is due to the float, not the conversion.  I would write a script to find the data that is out of bounds, and then fix those entries.  It might be a lot of manual work.  :-(

Comment: @Andrew currently I don't care the lost data, want to fix that without touch the old data, does converting to varchar before do that?

Comment: What is the largest integer allowed?  Once accuracy is lost, it cannot be re-gained

Comment: I don't need the lost number, I want the old numbers like 285.068 will stay as is but the next time I'll have such a number I want it more accurate like 285.068181818181800. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not understanding.  285.068 cannot be exactly represented as a float.  Think like a carpenter -- 258 1/2, 258 5/32, etc (always in 1/2^n increments). The closest such value to 285.068 is 258  557/8192 = 285.0679931640625 (note that the last 3 digits 625 = 5/8, a good clue).  Similarly, 285.068181818181800 also cannot be exactly represented as a float (note 800 != n/8).  Avoid floats.

Comment: You can store as a `VARCHAR`, but then you will have issues doing any type of arithmetic with it.  If you have 1 dollar and need to split it 3 ways, you get 33 cents each, plus 1 cent left over.  That is division is a killer for precision issues.  Multiply tends to double the number of digits needed.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

`13815500` is exactly representable in `FLOAT`.  But you are close to what Andrew talks about -- `16777217` is not exactly representable; it will be off by 1 Euro or dollar or whatever.

If you have no decimal places, your choices are

- `FLOAT`, which messes up above 16,777,216.
- `DECIMAL(9,0)` which can handle numbers up to about 1 billion.  *Caveat*:  If you need decimal places, say so!_
- `INT` which peaks at about 2 billion.
- `INT UNSIGNED` - limit about 4 billion (non-negative values only).

Each of the above datatypes mentioned above takes 4 bytes.  All but the last allow for negative values.  `FLOAT` will keep going, but lose bits at the bottom; the others "overflow".

Other options:  `DECIMAL(m,0)` with bigger numbers (m<=64), `DOUBLE` (huge floating range), `BIGINT` (huge integral range); each take more space.

The syntax is

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
    MODIFY col_name NEW_DATATYPE [NOT NULL];
```

(There is no need, and may be harm, in stepping through `VARCHAR`.)

General rule:  Use `DECIMAL` for money because it is "exact"; use `FLOAT` for measurements (such as sensors, distance, etc)

**More**

If the max value is 13815500, then `DECIMAL(64,56)` will hold any of your numbers, and handle up to 56 decimal places.  Furthermore, you can do basic arithmetic exactly on those numbers.  Caution:  If you will be `SUMming` a thousand such numbers, you need an extra 3 digits *before* the decimal point:  `DECIMAL(64,53)`.  For summing a million numbers:  `DECIMAL(64,50)`.

If your current data is sitting in a `FLOAT` column, then you only have about 7 significant digits; the rest was lost as the numbers were stored.  Can you recover the lost precision?  If so, start over with a suitable `DECIMAL`.  If not, then a numerical analyst will argue that you may as well stick with `FLOAT`.  A `SUM` will still be good to about 6-7 significant digits.  This is good enough for most uses.

You now have virtually all the knowledge of MySQL and numerical analysis; you decide what to do.

Comment: I have decimal places, I have number like: `285.068` that should be `285.068181818181800` and was rounded due to FLOAT issue. I don't need the lost number, I want the old numbers like the `285.068` will stay as is but the next time I'll have such a number I want it `285.068181818181800`, is this answer relevant? Thanks!

Comment: @Esther-I - Before I address the latest question, how many "significant digits" might you need to keep?  Those numbers are 6 and 18 significant digits.  So, I guess `DOUBLE` is out, since it stops at about 16.

Comment: I don't know in advance how many "significant digits" I may have. Example numbers I might have: `3748.863636363636500`, `12.102272727272728`, `28.977272727272727`, `1178636.363636363500000`.

Comment: Hmmm... Those seem to have about 16 digits, as if some step was using `DOUBLE`.  Also those numbers with "27" in them were either your fingers repeating or were relatively simple "rational" numbers.  (Example:  3/11 = 0.27272727... (forever)).  What will you be doing with the numbers? -- I am fishing for "how much precision is _really_ needed.

Comment: I need all the digits, I'm dealing with finance and Each digit is important in high sums.